Laravel custom Exception and logging
I've made a custom exception and being using it without any problems with the following structure
/* file1.php */
function myFunction() {    
    try {
        /* code */
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        Throw new CustomException ("My error message to the user");
    }
}

Then in file2 i do:
/* file2.php */
try {
    myFunction()
} catch (CustomException $th) {
    /* mail to user */
} catch (Exception $e) {
    /* mail to admin */
}

What I want is to always log the error that causes a CustomException. I know I can do $th->getPrevious() and from then get message, file, etc.
The problem is that there are multiple calls to "myFunction" in multiple files. Is there a way to avoid writing the $th->getPrevious() and stuff in every catch and always whenever a exception is thrown write a log line?

Typically in Laravel you'd use reportable and renderable exceptions and let the exception handler deal with them
